# Remote sniffing with ERSPAN to the desktop

Tags: cisco, ethernet, monitoring, cisco-7600, mirror

I know how to use both SPAN and RSPAN. If I'm not wrong, ERSPAN leads us to the possibility of remotely monitoring a router through an IP network and a GRE tunnel. However a tunnel end-point is needed.

My question is, is it possible for the tunnel endpoint to be a desktop computer to receive the mirrored traffic? I'm mostly looking for an OpenSource/Freware solution, since I guess a proprietary one would involve VMWare Vswitch or Nexus1000V.

Dynamips could be a solution, but I don't think any routers support ERSPAN.

I know about [OpenVswitch](http://openvswitch.org/), but it does not support ERSPAN.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are a couple of options, depending on how much traffic you will receive:

- If you're going to receive a lot of traffic, should use [gulp](http://staff.washington.edu/corey/gulp/), which runs on linux; [gulp](http://staff.washington.edu/corey/gulp/) requires the linux [pf_ring](http://www.ntop.org/products/pf_ring/) kernel module.
- If the bandwidth requirements are reasonable, you could simply use your laptop with [wireshark's ERSPAN decoder](https://www.wireshark.org/lists/wireshark-bugs/201009/msg00508.html); wireshark can see the protocols inside [ERSPAN](https://supportforums.cisco.com/document/139236/understanding-spanrspanand-erspan) v2 and v3 packets.  Use `ip proto 0x2f` as your capture filter, if you want to only capture ERSPAN traffic.  I use the wireshark to capture [ERSPAN](https://supportforums.cisco.com/document/139236/understanding-spanrspanand-erspan) from Catalyst6500 user ports when I need to remotely sniff a port without walking up to the switch with a laptop.  This works well for user ports and even some server ports (as long as they aren't sending tons of traffic)

Example Cat6500 ERSPAN config:

```
!
monitor session 2 type erspan-source
 source interface GigabitEthernet7/22
 destination
  erspan-id 1
  ! This is the ip address of gulp, or the wireshark laptop
  !    If using wireshark, capture with "ip proto 0x2f"
  ip address 10.1.1.5
  ! This is the IP address of the switch sourcing ERSPAN packets
  origin ip address 10.21.4.12
 no shutdown
```

Example Nexus9000 ERSPAN config:

```
monitor session 1 type erspan-source
  erspan-id 1
  ! Specify the vrf that ERSPAN will use to route to the destination IP
  !  NOTE: I have not found a way to use "vrf management" on the 9000 series
  vrf default
  ! This is the ip address of gulp, or the wireshark laptop
  !    If using wireshark, capture with "ip proto 0x2f"
  destination ip 10.5.69.226
  source interface port-channel1001 both
  no shut

! This is the IP address of the switch sourcing ERSPAN packets
monitor erspan origin ip-address 172.16.12.80 global
```

Comment: So essentially there is no need to "close" the GRE tunnel. It's just a matter of "formatting" the received traffic... isn't it ?

Comment: @radicetrentasei ERSPAN uses a unidirectional GRE tunnel and all gulp does is decapsulate the traffic into a linux virtual NIC driver.  Even when you enable keepalives on a typical Cisco IOS GRE tunnel, the keepalive packets contain their own response, which should be routed via the opposite tunnel back to the keepalive source.

Comment: AS I understand GRE tunnel between Cisco and Linux will not be a good solution to achieve traffic coming from the Internet to the start point "Cisco "

Comment: What qualifies as "a good solution" depends on your requirements.  For some requirements ERSPAN to a Linux sniffer is a good solution